# How to get value in promise

Tags: javascript, selenium

Tell me know how to use dataTest in describe func :(

```
xlsxFile('./src/scenario/Khanh.xlsx').then((rows) => {
    const dataTest = rows[0][1];
   })  

describe("EZT Admin Login", async () => {
    // console.log('obj', Array.from(obj))

  it("should read excel file  ", async () => {
    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that, One of them is to enclose the reading of the file in a function that returns that intended results and then call it inside your describe.

Comment: It mean return dataTest in func? Then I can using dataTest everywhere? I tried but have error dataTest is not defined :(
`xlsxFile("./src/scenario/Khanh.xlsx").then((rows) => {
  const dataTest = rows[0][1];
  return dataTest;
});

describe("EZT Admin Login", async () => {
  console.log("dataTest", dataTest);
  it("should read excel file  ", async () => {});
});`

Comment: you need to put it inside a function like function getDataTest(){\* your code**\} then call the getDataTest function wherever you need